# Pushnotification not removed from notificationbar in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In my application i received push notification from gcm, if i click on that push notification, my application will open and i need to remove my notification from notification bar. But , it is still on notification bar.

I used the following logic for generating push notification in my GCMIntentService class.

```
       mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,  new Intent(this, TipsActivity.class), 0);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TipsActivity.class), 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("Appname")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

So, please guide me how to remove my notification , when i click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You have to add the following line>..

```
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Try this and let me know the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

as per my guessing it is happening due to flag of notification

may be there is line in your code related to notification flag
 may be that flag is `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` so change that flag to `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

you will find this flag in generateNotification  logic if you not mentioned the flag then please specify it as FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

**FLAG_NO_CLEAR** means

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should not be canceled when the user clicks the Clear all button

and

**FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL** means

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user.

here is the sample line

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

where **notification** is object of **NotificationManager**
use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) link for refference

hope it will resolve your issue happy coding